# Python typing, if none is given return none

Tags: python, python-typing

Is it possible to write a typehint in python that guarantees if `None` is given to a function then `None` is returned?

For example this is possible:

```py
from typing import Dict, Union
def getMaybe(dictionary: Optional[Dict], key: str) -> Optional[str]:
    if dictionary is None:
        return dictionary

    return dictionary.get(key)
```

But then even when I know the argument has a value, the type signature doesn't guarantee the output will. For example:

```
def printer(msg: str):
    print(msg)

data = {'a': 'a'}
result = getMaybe(data, 'a')
printer(result)
```

Gives the error:

```
error: Argument of type "str | None" cannot be assigned to parameter "msg" of type "str" in function "printer"
  Type "str | None" cannot be assigned to type "str"
    Type "None" cannot be assigned to type "str" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

Is it possible to encode in the type signature that when `None` is given as an argument, then `None` is returned?

Comment: Check out `@overload`!  You want to define two different signatures for the function.

Comment: Would `Optional[str]` work?

Comment: The overload annotation sounds like a promising idea!

Comment: unrelated note: you don't need to use `typing.Dict`, you can just use the builtin `dict`.

Comment: This is in Python 3.8 sadly, but yeah `dict` typing is really nice in 3.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) is what you want:

```
from typing import Dict, Union, Optional, overload

@overload
def getMaybe(dictionary: None, key: str) -> None: ...

@overload
def getMaybe(dictionary: Dict, key: str) -> str: ...
    
def getMaybe(dictionary: Optional[Dict], key: str) -> Optional[str]:
    if dictionary is None:
        return dictionary

    return dictionary.get(key)
    

reveal_type(getMaybe(None, "")) # None
reveal_type(getMaybe({}, "")) # str
```